In optics, how do 2D ray diagrams generalize to 3D?
I'm learning optics, and I'm struggling to understand how ray diagrams in 2D effectively generalize to real world 3D optical systems.

I understand that we are considering systems that are rotationally symmetric around the principal axis. This is fine for rays that lie within a plane that contains the principal axis. In other words, rays that either intersect the principal axis or are parallel to it. In that case generalization is trivial by rotation around the principal axis.
But what about rays that are neither? In 3D, you can have rays that don't lie in any of the planes that contain the principal axis. Are those assumed non existent in 2D ray diagrams? Or is there some projection geometry trick that we can use to include them?

In systems where the principal optical axis changes because there is an angled mirror, like in a periscope , prisms or binoculars, how can 2D ray diagrams - or more generally 2D pictures - still be valid and correctly inform about 3D behavior? I'm having a hard time understanding how 2D raytracing can be helpful in a system where rotational symmetry is only piecewise, segment by segment so to speak, where a mirror effectively changes the principal axis direction. What happens to rays at the angled mirror? Can you apply the law of reflection there even though the system is not symmetric?


I've been looking through textbooks and I can't seem to find a detailed analysis of the 3D <-> 2D mapping between ray diagrams and real optical systems. At best rotational symmetry is mentioned but not really demonstrated. Are there any resources or texts that discuss this in details?
Note that my question is NOT about the paraxial approximation, where $\tan x = \sin x = x$. I'm happy to consider ray diagrams where that simplification is not made and accurate 2D geometry is maintained.



Point of personal clarification: "rays" means "geometric optics", aka the limit as $\lambda \rightarrow 0$? Edit: never mind. I just learned that there is a "geometric-optics" tag: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-optics

I think the question is answered by challenging the way it is framed: it is not about mapping between 2D and 3D, but about understanding how image is constructed for a thin lens:
for every point in a source we have a ray that passes through the center of the lens, and those that don't. Since the rays originate from the same point, we can always draw a plane through this point, the center of the lens, and the point where the ray of interest crosses the lens - the ray of interest is contained in this plane.
The diagrams like the ones quoted in the Q. are not demonstrating the rays, but rather rather what happens to an image, i.e., combinations of rays coming from many points. In other words, their value is mostly explicative/intuitive, rather than an attempt to rigorously explain how image is constructed.

Thank you for your answer! I'm pretty sure ray diagrams are not limited to thin lenses. Here's an example of using ray diagrams for thick lenses: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/02%3A_Lens_and_Mirror_Calculations/2.11%3A_Thick_Lenses. It's also used for flat, convex and concave mirrors.

@fouronnes discussions of thick lenses are based on the same principles of image construction as thin lenses, but less detailed: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/University_Physics_III_-Optics_and_Modern_Physics%28OpenStax%29/02%3A_Geometric_Optics_and_Image_Formation/2.05%3A_Thin_Lenses

see also: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/priplan.html, https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Thick-lens-model-The-dashed-lines-show-the-actual-paths-of-rays-passing-through-the_fig4_221433389

Approximations that involve paraxial rays or thin lenses assume lenses are perfect. Rays that come from an object point go to the corresponding image point. This is good enough for some simple systems. It also helps lay out optical elements for more complex systems before considering more accurate models.
Plane mirrors are not a problem. They just reflect a ray. In your top right picture, imagine the prisms were not there and the light entered and exited vertically. You would have essentially the same optical system. Plane mirrors just change the direction of the optical axis.
Real lenses are not perfect. If a lens was made with the perfect shape all rays parallel to the axis would meet within a wavelength or so from a point. Any deviation from perfect makes rays go in the wrong direction. The effect often becomes noticeable if the surface deviates from perfect by a wavelength of light or so. Lenses have to be incredibly accurate.
They are usually made from spherical surfaces because those are possible to make accurate to a wavelength of light. With a lot of care, it is possible to make slight deviations from spherical, but aspherical lenses are expensive. Spherical lenses are very close to the ideal shape. But the outer rim of a lens generally has a slightly different focal length than the part visited by paraxial rays. This causes an imperfection called spherical aberration.
There are more aberrations. I give more information in my answer to Is there a more accurate form of the mirror equation 1f=1u+1v?
The aberration you are asking about is coma. A cylinder or cone of rays that arrive from an angle are not focused to a point.
A large part of lens design is making the aberrations of one lens cancel those of another.

Thanks for the answer! Can you expend on your second paragraph? Doesn't the angled mirror also flip objects? If I wanted to continue a lens ray diagram through an angled mirror?

I think the question is not about sagittal rays that cross the optical axis, hence "coma" but rather about skew or even parabasal rays that do not cross the optical axis, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_(optics)#Special_rays "A parabasal ray is a ray that propagates close to some defined "base ray" rather than the optical axis.[14] This is more appropriate than the paraxial model in systems that lack symmetry about the optical axis. In computer modeling, parabasal rays are "real rays", that is rays that are treated without making the paraxial approximation....

...Parabasal rays about the optical axis are sometimes used to calculate first-order properties of optical systems."
